# I can't read or write a file using MARS - mips

Tags: file, io, mips, mars-simulator

I tried using the following code in order to open a new file for writing, write text to it from a memory buffer, then close it. I believe the txt file should be created in the directory in which the MARS script is saved, automatically, however there is no file. $v0 isn't negative, so I think no error occurred. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

```
        .data
fout:   .asciiz "testout.txt"      # filename for output
buffer: .asciiz "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
        .text
  ###############################################################
  # Open (for writing) a file that does not exist
  li   $v0, 13       # system call for open file
  la   $a0, fout     # output file name
  li   $a1, 1        # Open for writing (flags are 0: read, 1: write)
  li   $a2, 0        # mode is ignored
  syscall            # open a file (file descriptor returned in $v0)
  move $s6, $v0      # save the file descriptor 
  ###############################################################
  # Write to file just opened
  li   $v0, 15       # system call for write to file
  move $a0, $s6      # file descriptor 
  la   $a1, buffer   # address of buffer from which to write
  li   $a2, 44       # hardcoded buffer length
  syscall            # write to file
  ###############################################################
  # Close the file 
  li   $v0, 16       # system call for close file
  move $a0, $s6      # file descriptor to close
  syscall            # close file
  ###############################################################
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem was in the path: `fout: .asciiz "testout.txt"`. It needs to be the complete path with double `\\` instead of `\`:

`fout:.asciiz "C:\\Users\\Angry\\Desktop\\testout.txt"`